# Twitter-like following system

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I am working on a twitter clone in PHP for school, and I have one major problem. I cannot find a way to implement a follower system. There is a table for users, and I want to add a field that holds the ids of all of the users that each user follows.

Should I separate the ids with commas and then split them apart in PHP? And then I need to select all of the tweets from the tweets table that were tweeted by any of the users followers. Is there an SQL command that I can use? Something similar to

```
SELECT *
FROM tweets 
WHERE author='$followeduser'"
```

but where `$followeduser` is multiple ids.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a `USER_MASTER` table like this

```
USER_ID (int)
USER_NAME(varchar(50))
```

Create a table called `USER_FOLLOWERS` like this

```
USER_FOLLOWER_ID // Auto increment-Primary Key for this record
USER_ID (int)  // foriegn key to UserId column in USER_MASTER table
FOLLOWER_ID (int)  // foriegn key to UserId column in USER_MASTER table
```

Store the UserId in the first column and store the UserId of the User who follows this user in the `Follower_ID` column.

So your data will look like this

```
USER_ID    USER_NAME
--------------------------------------
1           SCOTT
2           JARED
3           MARC
4           ERIC

USER_FOLLOWER_ID    USER_ID   FOLLOWER_ID
--------------------------------------
1                    1          2
2                    1          3
3                    1          4
4                    2          1
```

So this means , The User Scott has 3 followers, Jared, Marc and Eric. User JARED HAS one Follower, that is SCOTT

To get the list of Followers for a user(ex : Scott (ID=1)) , you can do a Join between these 2 tables

```
  SELECT U. USER_ID, U.USER_NAME From USER_MASTER U
  INNER JOIN USER_FOLLOWERS UF ON U.USER_ID=UF.FOLLOWER_ID
  WHERE UF.USER_ID=1  // 1 is the ID of SCott
```

Comment: So if I do something like "SELECT FOLLOWER_ID FROM USER_FOLLOWERS WHERE USER_ID="$currentuser" I will get an array of all the follower IDs. How can I then select all of the tweets for each id? Would I use a for loop?

Comment: @user1460022 see my updated answer. You need to join the tweet table also

Answer (score 1):

Make a join table.

Putting all IDs in a list is **not the normalized way** and can lead to many many issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have a relations table where you have one column called user and second that is following. So if user 1 is following user 3 and 5, then you would have an entree where user = 1 following = 3 and user = 1 following = 5 (use whatever ID's you want). You also have your Tweets Table where you store all tweets. Youre going to want to make a query that joins the two tables